# Is there any pattern to specify target triples in GCC?

Tags: compiling, gcc, cross-compilation

The gcc compiler use target-triplets for cross-compilation. I see some of these target triples like "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu" (the most common). I understand what means but I don't know how specify another unix-like system instead "linux-gnu". Is there any document for it? and the "pc" seems be optional (should I care about this?), when I run a "config.guess" script, it returns me "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to cross compile, you must have (or build) a cross-compiler; gcc cannot, by default, just build for any target that it *could* be configured for.  There is a list of possibilities in the gcc source package, I believe.

Building a cross compiler toolchain is not a simple undertaking, so if you want to do that, you have to decide what it's for and ask more specific questions.

There's also a list of hosts/targets with notes [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/specific.html).  An asterisk indicates that any value can be used in that position (presumably this makes no difference to the compiler, and is simply a user defined label); the `pc` you are talking about may be such.

Answer (score 1):

`config.guess` is the document, actually.  But simply building a cross-gcc won't get you far if you don't also have the libraries for the target system.